# WPF Command that can access its target

Tags: wpf, icommand

I want to write a command in WPF that I can use in multiple places that will perform an operation on text in a textbox. Let's say the purpose of the command is to *Bold* some text by adding asterisks either side of it. The command would be added to a context menu and target the textbox.

Here are the problems:

- How do I know which textbox is being targeted? ICommand does not include a CommandTarget.
- How can I respond to changes in the textbox (e.g. if there is any text selected or not) in order to raise CanExecuteChanged? I know I can use the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event, but is there a more efficient way?

Here is how I imagine the XAML would look:

```
    <TextBox Name="TargetTextBox">
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Bold" Command="{x:Static Commands.MyBoldCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TargetTextBox}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: For your parameter you can use MultiBinding.

Comment: What about using the `CommandParamter` to pass in the TextBox? Alternatively, you could probably obtain the `ContextMenu` that the MenuItem is attached to, and check it's `PlacementTarget` to get the item it's attached to

Answer (score 2):

You could access the FontWeight via passing it in through a CommandParameter. Here is an example of that:

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Bold" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.FontWeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

**ICommand:**

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_MyCommand == null)
        {
            _MyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => this.MyCommandFunction(param)
                );
        }
        return _MyCommand;
    }
}
```

**MyCommandFunction:**

```
private void MyCommandFunction(object param)
{
    FontWeight fw = (FontWeight)param;
    fw = FontWeights.Bold; 
}
```

I just used a RelayCommand, but you can use a DelegateCommand if you like.You must bind the Command Parameter like that so that the datacontext of the menu item has a visual on the text box. Inside of it's normal scope, it doesn't. You will still need to update the view as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for my generic CommandBase which inherits from ICommand:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base class for all Commands.
/// </summary>
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current 
    /// state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data 
    /// to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data 
    /// to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Here are the steps I recommend:

1. Assign a string property (**MyTextProperty**) in your ViewModel to handle the Textbox text.
2. Create a command (**MyTextChangedCommand**) that inherits from the above **CommandBase** that takes a parameter of your ViewModel type (**YourViewModelType**). Then interact with your **MyTextProperty** directly by accessing the ViewModel passed to your command rather than trying to use CommandParameters.
3. Create a property in your ViewModel of type **MyTextChangedCommand** and make sure to instantiate it in the constructor of your ViewModel.

For your command binding in WPF I would use [Blend Interactivity for WPF v4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blend.Interctivity.WPF.v4.0/)

Here is how you would implement your TextBox (assuming you reference Microsoft.Expression.Interactions as "i":

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyTextProperty">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                Command="{Binding Path=MyTextChangedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Whatever" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```